# How to convert this array of strings to array object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I ma having this string returned from my C# code. I need to implement Google Maps. How d i convert this into array.

## String

```
var array = [["Andover - Wyevale Garden Centre","Concession A","Andover Garden Centre","Salisbury Road","Andover","SP11 7DN","01264 710114","14.9 miles","51.1998552","-1.5111393"],
    ["Portsmouth - Gunwharf Quays","Unit 29","Gunwharf Quays","Portsmouth","Hampshire","PO1 3TZ","02392 819558","20.8 miles","50.7963663","-1.1065603"],
    ["Chichester","83 North Street","Chichester","West Sussex","PO19 1LQ","01243 380058","25.9 miles","50.837269","-0.77846"],
    ["Newport - Isle of Wight","117/119 High Street","Newport","Isle of Wight","PO30 1TP","01983 527485","27.1 miles","50.700399","-1.294872"],
    ["Guildford","20-21 North Street","Guildford","Surrey","GU1 4AF","01483 456978","29.8 miles","51.2369881","-0.5731617"]]
```

i dont know but when i do `array[1][0]` it should return "`Portsmouth`" in chrome console   BUT it is coming as `undefined`.

I suspect array variable is identified as string and not array.

when i do `array[0][4]` i get "A" as output.

Please help

Comment: The nested `"` make it invalid JavaScript, hence the code cannot even be executed. And of course `"` denotes the beginning (or end) of a string literal, so `array` is certainly not an array.

Comment: I couldn't find any `string` or `array`

Comment: I copied the data from console window. so thats why its nested BUT there is no " at the start of the string.#

Comment: Well, you should post what you *actually* have in your code. As it is now, `array` would be indeed an array of arrays, so using `JSON.parse` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I completely agree with you... next time will take care of this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this .. this will running on my side .

```
var array = '[["d","ddd","sadasd","Salisbury Road","Andover","SP11 7DN","01264 710114","14.9 miles","51.1998552","-1.5111393"],["Portsmouth - Gunwharf Quays","Unit 29","Gunwharf Quays","Portsmouth","Hampshire","PO1 3TZ","02392 819558","20.8 miles","50.7963663","-1.1065603"],["Chichester","83 North Street","Chichester","West Sussex","PO19 1LQ","01243 380058","25.9 miles","50.837269","-0.77846"],["Newport - Isle of Wight","117/119 High Street","Newport","Isle of Wight","PO30 1TP","01983 527485","27.1 miles","50.700399","-1.294872"],["Guildford","20-21 North Street","Guildford","Surrey","GU1 4AF","01483 456978","29.8 miles","51.2369881","-0.5731617"]]'



var arrayObj = JSON.parse(array)
console.log(arrayObj)
console.log(arrayObj[1][0])
```

// returns--- 
Portsmouth - Gunwharf Quays

Comment: Thanks Mate.. I got it working by removing ' and ; at the end ...using JSON.parse(array) helped me...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your encompassing double quotes and include a terminating semi-colon `;`...

```
var array = [["Andover - Wyevale Garden Centre","Concession A","Andover Garden Centre","Salisbury Road","Andover","SP11 7DN","01264 710114","14.9 miles","51.1998552","-1.5111393"],
    ["Portsmouth - Gunwharf Quays","Unit 29","Gunwharf Quays","Portsmouth","Hampshire","PO1 3TZ","02392 819558","20.8 miles","50.7963663","-1.1065603"],
    ["Chichester","83 North Street","Chichester","West Sussex","PO19 1LQ","01243 380058","25.9 miles","50.837269","-0.77846"],
    ["Newport - Isle of Wight","117/119 High Street","Newport","Isle of Wight","PO30 1TP","01983 527485","27.1 miles","50.700399","-1.294872"],
    ["Guildford","20-21 North Street","Guildford","Surrey","GU1 4AF","01483 456978","29.8 miles","51.2369881","-0.5731617"]];
```

Comment: well, i tried it with ' and it is still not working. when i do array[1] i get [ in console

Comment: Sorry wasn't paying attention there, you need to remove the outer quotes altogether.

Answer (score 1):

OK try this:

```
var array = [["Andover - Wyevale Garden Centre","Concession A","Andover Garden Centre","Salisbury Road","Andover","SP11 7DN","01264 710114","14.9 miles","51.1998552","-1.5111393"],
    ["Portsmouth - Gunwharf Quays","Unit 29","Gunwharf Quays","Portsmouth","Hampshire","PO1 3TZ","02392 819558","20.8 miles","50.7963663","-1.1065603"],
    ["Chichester","83 North Street","Chichester","West Sussex","PO19 1LQ","01243 380058","25.9 miles","50.837269","-0.77846"],
    ["Newport - Isle of Wight","117/119 High Street","Newport","Isle of Wight","PO30 1TP","01983 527485","27.1 miles","50.700399","-1.294872"],
    ["Guildford","20-21 North Street","Guildford","Surrey","GU1 4AF","01483 456978","29.8 miles","51.2369881","-0.5731617"]];
```